# Mocking Django database calls

Tags: django, exception, mocking

I am trying to unit test a Django application and in the process mocking a database call using [Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/getting-started.html) as follows (where Record is a Django model):

```
Record.objects.get = Mock()
Record.objects.get.side_effect = Exception("Record.DoesNotExist") # Exception as a string
```

and I am catching the exception as follows:

```
except Record.DoesNotExist:
    return HttpResponseRedirect("http://www.somesite.com")
```

Then I get the following error on running the test:

```
Exception: Record.DoesNotExist
```

If instead I mock the exception as follows:

```
Record.objects.get.side_effect = Exception(Record.DoesNotExist) # Exception as a class
```

Then I get the following error on running the test:

```
Exception: <class 'supersales.plugin.models.DoesNotExist'>
```

Could somebody explain why can't it catch the exception even when there is a try-except block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing two different things, neither of which is the same as actually raising the `Record.DoesNotExist` exception. You can try them out in your console to see.

The first is raising an exception of class Exception (the base class for all exceptions), with the *message* "Record.DoesNotExist". Your try/except is not catching it because it (correctly) is only catching the actual `DoesNotExist` class.

The second is also raising an exception of class Exception, except this time the message is the class `Record.DoesNotExist`. Again, the try/except will not catch it because the class of the exception - as opposed to the message - is wrong.

Instead, you simply need to pass the actual exception class to the side_effect:

```
Record.objects.get.side_effect = Record.DoesNotExist
```

Comment: Yes I figured that out after sometime. As this should have made obvious, I am a Python newbie. Thanks a lot for you reply though.